# LINQ query takes 1600 times longer in Visual Studio than LINQPad

Tags: c#, linq

I am building a query for a search box in ASP MVC. The query takes 10 milliseconds in LINQPad and 16 seconds in Visual Studio. Is there any way that I can improve the query or the time response for the query?

```
 var queryOracle = (from TS in dbOracle.BI_TYPE_SERVICE
                           join MS in dbOracle.BI_MTR_SRV on TS.BI_ACCT equals MS.BI_ACCT
                           join SL in dbOracle.BI_SRV_LOC on MS.BI_SRV_LOC_NBR equals SL.BI_SRV_LOC_NBR
                           join C in dbOracle.BI_CONSUMER on TS.BI_ACCT equals C.BI_ACCT
                           join P in dbOracle.BI_PERSONAL on C.BI_CUST_NBR equals P.BI_CUST_NBR
                           join STR in dbOracle.BI_SRV_STAT_REF on TS.BI_SRV_STAT_CD equals STR.BI_SRV_STAT_CD
                           where P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "2B" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "2D" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "FO" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CC" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "8" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "SE" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "9" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "BD" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CN" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CR" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CS" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "M1" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "M2" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "M3" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "MR"
                           where P.BI_ACCT == 0
                           where P.BI_FORMAT_NAME.StartsWith(term) || SL.BI_ADDR1.StartsWith(term) || MS.BI_MTR_NBR.StartsWith(term) || TS.BI_ACCT.ToString().StartsWith(term)


                           select new
                           {
                               LocationID = SL.BI_SRV_MAP_LOC,
                               MeterNumber = MS.BI_MTR_NBR,
                               AccountNumber = TS.BI_ACCT,
                               ServiceStatCD = TS.BI_SRV_STAT_CD,
                               ServiceStatus = STR.BI_SRV_STAT_DESC,
                               Name = P.BI_FORMAT_NAME,
                               ServiceAddr = SL.BI_ADDR1,
                               ServiceCity = SL.BI_CITY,
                               CustomerNumber = C.BI_CUST_NBR,
                               ServiceCNTY = SL.BI_CNTY_CD,
                               ServiceTOWN = SL.BI_TOWN_CD,
                               HomeAreaCode = P.BI_HOME_AREA_CD,
                               HomePhone = P.BI_HOME_PHN,
                               BusAreaCode = P.BI_BUS_AREA_CD,
                               BusPhone = P.BI_BUS_PHN,
                               MobileAreaCode = P.BI_MOBL_AREA_CD,
                               MobilePhone = P.BI_MOBL_PHN
                           }).AsNoTracking().Take(12).ToList();
```

Comment: You tested in Release mode in VS, didn't you ?

Comment: It could be the VS code include initializing the connection while the Linqpad simply reuse existing connection

Comment: Maybe it's not your query that's slowing down the MVC side?  Are you doing other operations within the MVC action, but testing only the query itself within LINQPad?  You could use the stopwatch class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to test specifically the time involved with just running the query part within the MVC code to see if it differs in time from the LINQPad query execution.

Comment: Did you try to profile and see if your code really hangs specifically on this query?

Comment: On a side note if you use navigation properties instead of joins you should end up with a more readable Linq query (assuming you have navigation properties).  Here's a good article about it. https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: By the way, `where P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "2B" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "2D" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "FO" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CC" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "8" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "SE" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "9" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "BD" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CN" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CR" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "CS" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "M1" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "M2" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "M3" || P.BI_ADDR_TYPE != "MR"` is pretty useless

Comment: Thank you however I tested in release mode and also I added an Stopwatch before the query so is the only process that I am measuring the time.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The `Take` will be turned into part of the SQL Query, so it's not creating thousands of object and then reducing it down to the first 12.

Comment: @Thomas presumably the OP actually wanted to and those together.  It would be simpiler with something like `!new []{"2B", "2D", ...}.Contains(P.BI_ADDR_TYPE)` in that case

Comment: Please don't say that you are comparing LINQ over objects with LINQ to sql.

Comment: @CesarD Are you executing the query in LINQPad in "Results to Rich Text" or "Results to Data Grids" mode?  Does it make a difference to timings if you switch to the other mode?

Comment: When I use Data Grids it takes 0.010 seconds and with Rich text is more than 15 seconds

Comment: Note that LINQPad uses `linq2sql`, while you're using `EntityFramework` (as evidenced by `.AsNoTracking()`). I don't really have an explanation (your query is extremely hard to grok without spending considerable time) - but you've got an unreliable comparison when using two different technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and was wondering why. In my case there was a breakpoint in code which slowed down the whole thing when running within the VS environment.

So disable the breakpoints which are used within the query within VS and it should be faster.

Answer (score -3):

First question: why don't you use a separate function ?

I would recommend doing this by using
[Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

And I would definitely not run this in the main thread.

I would recommend to use :

[Task.Factory.StartNew()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx)

Would be important to know what code you use apart from that query.

Maybe it is not the query itself that needs the time.

Best regards